# Can we prioritize ActiveMQ messages based on message properties or headers?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

This is followup question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111337/how-to-set-message-priority-for-embedded-activemq-using-spring-jmstemplate)

I am setting few application specific properties on messages and i want the messages to be prioritized based on those specific property values
For example :

```
Message message = session.createTextMessage("hello world!");
message.setStringProperty("myProperty","100");
producer.send(message )
```

Here I want messages to be prioritize based on value of `myProperty`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ doesn't support prioritizing delivery based on arbitrary message headers/properties. Only `JMSPriority` is supported as a way to prioritize message delivery.